# Can i configure a feature to run only after all other features in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a few feature files. Before they are executed, I first execute a specific feature file in order to get a parameter that is used by all other feature files. Getting that parameter, however, creates a record in the DB. So, I need to run another feature file after all other feature files are executed, in order to delete this new record. Is there a way i can do this? preferably through the karate-config file so that i can make sure to use correct parameters according to specifed environment. ive looked for quite a while and doesnt seem like a @afterall hook or annotation exists